# Change all negative values to positive values of the same magnitude (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix of negative and positive values, I've tried using an if loop to change the negative ones to positive:

```
if A(A<0)
    A = A.*(-1);
end
```

but it doesn't seem to do anything, what do?

Comment: Luis forgot the `=`, `ind = A < 0; A(ind) = -A(ind);`

Comment: @user1543042 Thanks! I realized and removed the comment (I couldn't edit it anymore)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use `abs`:

```
>> A = [-1,2,-3,4,-5]

A =

    -1     2    -3     4    -5

>> abs(A)

ans =

     1     2     3     4     5
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `abs` is the right thing to do here, but just in case you come across a similar (but not identical) problem, the pattern you were looking for is this:

```
A(A < 0) = -A(A < 0);
```

This uses *[logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html?refresh=true#bq7eg38)* on `A` to select the negative elements and negate them.

Comment: Maybe `ind = A<0; A(ind) = -A(ind);` to save some operations